# Immediately show autocomplete on Android

Tags: android, autocomplete, letter

The Android autocomplete only starts after two letters. How can I make it so the list appears when the field is just selected?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To get the autocomplete to show on focus add focus listener and show the drop down when the field gets focus, like this:

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(hasFocus){
      editText.showDropDown();
    }
  }
});
```

Or just call editText.showDropDown() if you don't need the focus part.

Comment: This one worked best for me. I wanted it to show up when user clicks on it so instead of Focus I used onClick.

Comment: simple concise and... the best!

Comment: thanks, without this, autocomplete items in dialog mode are in back,

Answer (score 9):

Have a look to [setThreshold](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#setThreshold%28int%29) method:

> *public void **setThreshold** (int*
>   threshold)
>   Since: API Level 1
>   Specifies the minimum number of
>   characters the user has to type in the
>   edit box before the drop down list is
>   shown.
>   When threshold is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is applied.

Comment: Is there anyway to make to it 0?

Comment: When threshold is less than or equals 0, a threshold of 1 is applied.

Comment: So there is no way to make it so that just selecting reveals all the options?

Comment: @Mit Afaik, there's no way to do that.

Comment: What is it supposed to auto-complete if there's no text?

Comment: @Falmarri all the auto-complete options? Its a pretty common use case when there is a fewer number of options.

Answer (score 9):

Extend the AutoCompleteTextView, overriding the enoughToFilter() methods and the threshold methods so that it doesn't replace the 0 threshold with a 1 threshold:

```
public class MyAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {

    private int myThreshold;

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public void setThreshold(int threshold) {
        if (threshold < 0) {
            threshold = 0;
        }
        myThreshold = threshold;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean enoughToFilter() {
        return getText().length() >= myThreshold;
    }

    @Override
    public int getThreshold() {
        return myThreshold;
    }

}
```

Comment: This won't show the drop down at once, you will still need to start typing.

Answer (score 2):

For people who want to change threshold using SearchView you have to use:

```
SearchView.SearchAutoComplete complete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete)search.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
complete.setThreshold(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pad your adapter with one/two white character on left depending on the threshold setting.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate method of changing the setting in your XML**: 
As mentioned by others you need to set your '[Auto Completion Threshold](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html#getThreshold())' to 1

Other than what @systempuntoout mentioned.

You can also do that in your XML file as shown

```
<AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/edittext_id"
    android:inputType="textAutoComplete"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
/>
```

Note the line : **android:completionThreshold="1"**