# AutoCompleteTextView in alertDialog box

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, autocompletetextview

Here in my app I create a dialog box which contain an autocomplete view. In the autoComplete view I want it to pop down the suggestions.when I enter names. But the problem is that it gives only 2 suggestions.

Here is the code for my autocomplete view in the XML file

```
<com.example.netmdapp1.CustomAutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/customautocomplete"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:completionThreshold="3"
    android:scrollbars="vertical" />
```

And here is my CustomAutoCompleteTextView class

```
public class CustomAutoCompleteTextView extends AutoCompleteTextView {
    HashMap<String, String>hm;

    public CustomAutoCompleteTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected CharSequence convertSelectionToString(Object selectedItem) {
         hm = (HashMap<String, String>)selectedItem;
         return hm.get("name");
    }

    public String getid() {
        return hm.get("id");
    }
}
```

And the code for set adapter to my autocomplete textView is given below

```
final CustomAutoCompleteTextView autoComplete = new CustomAutoCompleteTextView(getParent(), null);
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getParent(), patientList, R.layout.autocomplete_texts, from, to);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should have to look at this:
**[android-immediate-auto-complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235330/android-immediate-auto-complete)**

It will help you.

Feel free to comment.

Comment: hi thanx for ur response. this help me a lot a new information for me.

But actually this is not my expected answer.

Comment: have you try with increase the android:completionThreshold="5" value ?

Comment: but i would like to know more about it..
when i type on the autocomplete Text view it pop up only 2 suggestions. i need all the available suggestions..

Comment: for example my adapter hold 3 names which start with letter "R",

when i type "R" on the box i want to get all 3 names on my suggestion list(dropDown list) but now it only give 2 suggestions

Comment: i think the problem is that i am using the autoComplete View in a alertBox , is it currect?

Comment: Hummm not sure. but might be possible. Do one thing, use same code in normal activity instead of the alert dialog and see its effect. If your problem get solve there then yes it should because of you are using it in to the alert Dialog.

Comment: ok.. is there any option for list all the suggestions. why it display 2 items only.? is it becoz of the siz of alert dialog box?

Comment: i am not sure but might be because of that. You can also try another thing is. Made custom Alert dialog with your custom layout and then try with same.

Comment: u just great iDroid. i inflate the alert box. and now its working as my wish. thanks thanks for ur suggestions and response

Comment: if u dont mind pls send ur mail id to ranjithsankar.exe@gmail.com

Comment: If you got right answer then you can accept the answer as accepted.