# creating an AutoCompleteTextView inside alertDialog

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-alertdialog, autocompletetextview

I am trying to add an AutoCompleteTextBox inside an AlertDialog but I have no Idea how to do that. Any help regarding the same would be appreciated. Also In that AutoCompleteTextBox , I want to display the places through google Places API. I have implemented the google Places API for that and it shows the result if I run the url for that but when I enter 2 or more character in the AutoCompleteText Box it shows the following Error:

```
12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class fragment
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:371)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2340)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow$DropDownListView.obtainView(ListPopupWindow.java:1236)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.buildDropDown(ListPopupWindow.java:1123)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:532)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown(AutoCompleteTextView.java:1081)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.updateDropDownForFilter(AutoCompleteTextView.java:956)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView.onFilterComplete(AutoCompleteTextView.java:938)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:285)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #47: Duplicate id 0x7f05000e, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:676)
    12-20 15:28:39.020: E/AndroidRuntime(19180):    ... 22 more
```

Below is how I implemented the adapter:

```
AutoCompleteTextView autoCompView = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1);
autoCompView.setAdapter(new PlacesAutoCompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item));
```

and the AutoCompleteTextView in list_item is as follows:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/BookCabtxt"
        android:ems="10"
        >
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Note: This is just for trial purpose. In actual , I want to put this AutoCompleteTextView inside an AlertDialog. So Mainly I have 2 Doubts:

```
1>creating an AutoCompleteTextView inside alertDialog
2>Generating results in that AutoCompleteTextView
```

If there is anything that is not clear please ask in the comments.thanks in advance and pardon my english and ignorance in andoid development as well.

Comment: what is line 47 in xml

Comment: Can you show us the whole xml, indicating which line is the 47 please?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008183/error-inflating-fragment-in-dialog-the-second-time

Comment: Here is the code on line 47:<fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/group1"
        map:cameraTargetLat="12.9667"
        map:cameraTargetLng="77.5667"
        map:cameraZoom="12" />

Comment: make sure `YourActivity extends FragmentActivity`

Comment: @Ketan its already there. Can you suggest something else.

Comment: Just Go through this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235330/android-immediate-auto-complete

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the view you created for the Dialog. You should have something that looks like this.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this);
final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.my_layout, null); 
AutoCompleteTextView textViewCountry = (AutoCompleteTextView)textEntryView.findViewById(com.example.FindItNear.R.id.autocomplete_radius);
```

Here is a link which may help you: [AutoCompleteTextView implementation on the AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792701/autocompletetextview-implementation-on-the-alertdialog)